What is the Fourier transform of the product of Vandermonte Polynomial and a Gaussian
What is the Fourier transform of an N-variable function? $\alpha$ is a positive number.
$$\exp(-\alpha\sum^N_i x_i^2 )\prod_{1\leq i<j \leq N}(x_i-x_j)$$

Here is a quick go at it.
We have
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{ikx} e^{-\alpha x^2} x^n dx & = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-k^2/4 \alpha} e^{-\alpha (x+ik/2 \alpha)^2} x^n dx
\nonumber \\
& = e^{-k^2/4 \alpha} \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\alpha x^2} (x-ik/2 \alpha )^n dx
\nonumber \\
& = e^{-k^2/4 \alpha} \sum_{r=0}^n \binom nr (ik/2 \alpha)^{n-r}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\alpha x^2} x^r dx
\nonumber \\
& = e^{-k^2/4 \alpha} \sum_{r \; even}^n \binom nr (ik/2 \alpha)^{n-r} (-1)^r \frac{\partial^r}{\partial \alpha^r}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\alpha x^2} dx
\nonumber \\
& = e^{-k^2/4 \alpha} \sum_{r \; even}^n \binom nr (\frac{ik}{2 \alpha})^{n-r} \frac{\partial^r}{\partial \alpha^r} \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\alpha}}
\nonumber \\
& = e^{-k^2/4 \alpha} \sum_{r \; even}^n \binom nr (\frac{ik}{2 \alpha})^{n-r} \frac{1}{2} \frac{3}{2} \cdots \frac{2r-1}{2} \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\alpha^{r/2}}
\nonumber \\
& = \sqrt{\pi} e^{-k^2/4 \alpha} \sum_{r \; even}^n \binom nr \frac{1}{2^n} \frac{(ik)^{n-r}}{\alpha^{n-r/2}} 1 \cdot 3 \cdots (2r-1) 
\nonumber \\
& = \sqrt{\pi} \alpha^{-n/2} e^{-k^2/4 \alpha} \sum_{r \; even}^n \binom nr \frac{1}{2^n} (ik / \sqrt{\alpha})^{n-r} \frac{(2r-1)!}{2^{r-1} (r-1)!} 
\nonumber \\
& = \sqrt{\pi} \alpha^{-n/2} e^{-k^2/4 \alpha} P_n (ik/\sqrt{\alpha})
\end{align}
So
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{ik_ix_i} e^{-\alpha x_i^2} x_i^n dx_i & = \sqrt{\pi} \alpha^{-n/2} e^{-k_i^2/4 \alpha} P_n (ik_i /\sqrt{\alpha})
\end{align}
We have
\begin{align}
\prod_{1 \leq i < j \leq N} (x_i-x_j) = \sum_\sigma sgn (\sigma) \prod_{i=1}^N x_i^{\sigma (i)-1}
\end{align}
where $\sigma$ is a permutation of $\{ 1,2, \dots , N \}$. This follows from the Vandermonde determinant and Leibniz Formula for the Determinant. Using the above result we have
\begin{align}
& \int_{-\infty}^\infty \cdots \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{i\sum_{i=1}^N k_ix_i} e^{-\alpha \sum_{i=1}^N x_i^2} \prod_{1 \leq i < j \leq N} (x_i-x_j) dx_1 \cdots dx_N 
\nonumber \\
& = \pi^{N/2} \alpha^{-N(N-1)/4} \sum_\sigma sgn (\sigma) \prod_{i=1}^N e^{-k_i^2/4 \alpha} P_{\sigma (i)-1} (ik_i /\sqrt{\alpha})
\nonumber \\
& = e^{-\sum_{i=1}^Nk_i^2/4 \alpha} \cdot \pi^{N/2} \alpha^{-N(N-1)/4} \sum_\sigma sgn (\sigma) \prod_{i=1}^N P_{\sigma (i)-1} (ik_i /\sqrt{\alpha})
\end{align}
I don't know if this simplifies.
